# commiting multiple folders in chronological order into git

Tags: git, backup

I have several hundred backups of a web site, one per folder. I want to put them into a git repository, each backup as a version. The changes concern mostly image files and 2 database backups per day. The size is around 25 GB an increasing.
Is there a way to tell git to take one of the folders and commit it into the repository, then take the next folder an commit the changes, until they are all commited? Or do I have to copy each folder into the first folder, commit and continue with next folder?
Identical files are hardlinked between folders.
I would like to commit each backup with it's timestamps, but as far as I understand I can supply that with each commit.
So the main information I was looking for is really about specifying a folder not part of the git repository an committing the changes into the repository.

Comment: Under the assumption that you can order those backups by name/date, you could write a shell script that 1) initialises a Git repo, 2) gets the desired commit date of the next backup, 3) overwrite the contents of the working tree of a Git repo with the contents of that backup 4) add and commit using the desired date.

Comment: Do your backup folders follow some naming convention (e.g. `backup_2010_10_09`)?

Comment: Worth noting is that Git's achilles heel is binary data. While using Git as a backup tool for binary files would certainly work to some extent, it would be a good idea to keep an eye on memory and CPU usage -- at some point it may start to take a very long time to compress the data. You may want to disable delta compression.

Comment: @Jubobs They are numbered with the highest number being the oldest backup. I will find a way to get the date of the backup though. I can just look for the last database backups. Those have a naming convention with date and time. I was kind of sure I have to write a script. I was just wondering if there is a way, where I don't have to copy the folders into the working tree first.

Comment: @jsageryd Is it correct that this binary data problem might also apply if the image files have no changes, but are only added and removed?

Comment: @Javatasse: if the files are truly identical, Git is able to deal with them easily. If they differ, Git may attempt to do delta-compression on them. How effective this is depends on (in a theoretical sense) their Shannon entropy: a well compressed file has a high Shannon entropy and will not delta-compress well with anything else. Different image formats have different Shannon entropies, but for those that are high, if they have a consistent name pattern, you can instruct Git not to attempt to delta-compress them against each other.

Comment: @Javatasse Yes. Git stores everything in a content-addressed pool of objects. If you change an existing object, a new object will be created. So in effect, changing an existing object and adding a new one is the same thing. Delta compression happens on objects that are similar, regardless of whether or not they are related.

Comment: For more about this, see, e.g., https://www.kennethghartman.com/shannon-entropy-of-file-formats/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell git to take one of the folders and commit it into the repository, then take the next folder an commit the changes

There is no a *simple automatic* way, but there is a semi-automatic way. You have to manipulate `GIT_WORK_TREE` or option `--work-tree`. Something like that:

```
cd first-version
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first-version"
git --work-tree=../second-version add -A
git commit -m "second-version"
```

and repeat for every directory. If all directories have regular, names you can run a loop:

```
for version_dir in ../*-version; do
    git --work-tree=$version_dir add -A
    git commit -m "$version_dir"
done
```

> I would like to commit them with their timestamps

`git` doesn't preserve timestamps of files/directories, only of commits.

Comment: Your proposal seems to be what I am looking for. I did mean to specify a timestamp for the commit, to be able to check out the state from a specific date.

Comment: To specify an author and/or committer date per commit, set the environment variables GIT_AUTHOR_DATE and/or GIT_COMMITTER_DATE for the `git commit` command.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @phd is the prefect answer for my question.

However, a git-only solution is slow in this regard, particularly the line

> git --work-tree=../second-version add -A

Appearently git doesn't recognize easily that identical files are added to the staging.

So, since am working on a Linux system, I used rsync to synchronize my local copy with each folder.

Additionally I am using git lfs for image files. The problem here is that those files are not automatically moved to the lfs system, so I have to migrate them manually. In a script I execute the following command from within the folder of my local copy:

> rsync -a ../backupfolder_[$NUMBER]/* . --delete
>
> git add -A
>
> git commit -m "$cmessage"
>
> git lfs migrate import --include="folder/imagefolder1/**"
>
> git lfs migrate import --include="imagefolder2/**"
>
> git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
>
> git gc --prune=now