# How to change versioned folders into git versions and branches?

Tags: git

When I initially started out this project I was using git to track daily changes made to my code, then when I made a "major" change to the way something was done in my project I copied the files into a new folder with a version number.

I also then started needing to maintain code which is similar but with minor differences based on location. I ended up creating 3-4 different repositories with one for each location. At the time I didn't anticipate there would be so much in common with the code present in each of these locations, leading to a great deal of duplication in effort to copy the files across.

I'm not too familiar with all of the different more advanced commands in git but what I think I would like to have is a single repository with each of stages that I had saved as a versioned-folder as an actual git version tag and each of the different locations setup as a branch.

I think I could get the repository into this condition by manually copying the files into a brand new repository and adding them this way. If possible though, I would like to keep my original history and just somehow get it into this condition. Is this even possible or is this just a huge mess at this point requiring a new setup and fresh start?

*Here is a directory layout*

```
04/26/2019  12:06 PM    <DIR>          .
04/26/2019  12:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/17/2019  04:34 PM    <DIR>          .git
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          1.0 Transaction Groups
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          2.0 NBD Integrated
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          3.0 Python Implementation
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          4.1 Gateway-Side
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          4.2 Client-Side
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          5.1 Demonstration
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          5.2 Objects Demo
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          6.0 Recipe Management
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          6.1 Recipe Management Demonstration
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          7.0 Recipe Management SC Release
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          7.1 SC Release HMI Move
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          7.2 SC Release Tag Caching
04/15/2019  12:55 PM    <DIR>          Broken Tag Search
06/20/2018  12:02 PM    <DIR>          Client Native Launch
12/30/2018  01:52 PM    <DIR>          Diagnostics Screen
09/26/2018  03:46 PM    <DIR>          Done File
05/13/2019  02:11 PM    <DIR>          ESX Scripting
05/17/2018  02:48 PM    <DIR>          Historian
12/30/2018  11:57 AM    <DIR>          Manual Screens
02/06/2018  01:46 PM    <DIR>          Sample Code
05/16/2018  10:39 AM    <DIR>          SQL
04/16/2019  01:20 PM    <DIR>          System Testing
04/02/2018  04:28 PM    <DIR>          Web Scraper
```

Note that there are a number of different directories which are numbered. Each of these likely could be / have been a versioned release number. I also have several other complete repositories which share a significant number of similarities (at this point) between the files.

I would like to end up tracking changes on this inside a single repository using release versions `git tag` and move in the files present in the other repositories to be as different branches.

Would it be possible to save the commit history on each of these files while moving it into this (better) setup or will I need to just copy the files over one at a time and end up losing the previous history?

Comment: Use tags instead.

Comment: Do each of your copies have a `.git` folder? If so, have you already been tracking the changes by committing them in each of these copies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commiting multiple folders in chronological order into git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802316/commiting-multiple-folders-in-chronological-order-into-git)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you actually mean by "repository," but in Git lingo, a repository refers to your entire project, including all branches, tags, etc.  Assuming you are creating completely new repositories for each minor version, then the sensible thing to do would be to stop doing that, and instead just create new *branches* for each slightly different version of your code base.

Comment: I had setup 3 different repositories, each for a different location where code would be run. This seemed sensible at the time when I had originally envisioned there would be more substantial differences between each of these projects. You're right that in hindsight it wasn't the best solution.

Comment: I was using folders/directories inside each of these numbered for major revisions.

Comment: This goes against Git's paradigm.  In Git, you manage versions though branches or maybe tags, e.g. you would create a release branch for a certain major or minor version.  I strongly recommend that you review the basics of Git workflow, because you may be heading down the wrong path now.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not too familiar with all of the different more advanced commands in git...

What you want to do doesn't require any advanced commands. You can use `git branch`, `git add`, `git commit`, and `git tag` to do just about everything you want.

Comment: I think `git tag` is the one I never remember which would be most helpful. Mainly what I was looking for here is if there's some way of saving my original commit history associated with the files while bringing everything together into a single properly branched and tagged repository.

Comment: @ChickenMax If you have been keeping version control history in each of your copies, you should also read about `git remote` which can help you pull in that history into a central repo.